# Update the Selection according to radio button

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, api

I've started learning Angularjs. I was following w3schools tutorial and I needed to try out something.

Here I want to list the dropdown according to the radio button I've checked. (When I select Name, I need only the names in dropdown, when I select City, I need only the Cities in dropdown and so on).

```
    <body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
     <div>
        <input type="radio" ng-model="selection" value="Name">Name
        <input type="radio" ng-model="selection" value="Country">Country
        <input type="radio" ng-model="selection" value="City">City
        <br>
       <div ng-switch="selection">
        <div ng-switch-when="Name">
         <ul>
           <li ng-repeat="x in names">{{x.Name}}</li>
         </ul>
        </div>
        <div ng-switch-when="Country">
         <ul>
           <li ng-repeat="x in names">{{x.Country}}</li>
         </ul>
        </div>
        <div ng-switch-when="City">
         <ul>
           <li ng-repeat="x in names">{{x.City}}</li>
         </ul>
        </div>
       </div>
       <br>
      <select ng-model="selectedName" ng-options="x.Name for x in names"></select>
     </div>
    </body>
```

And this is the angular script file.

```
    var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);
    app.controller('myController', function($scope,$http){
      $http.get('http://www.w3schools.com/angular/customers.php')
     .then(function(response){
      $scope.names = response.data.records;
      });
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly, for your `<select>` element you want to conditionally display the label based on the selection from the `ng-model="selection"` radio input item. You can use a function within your `ng-options` to target a property for the label based on the selection passing in both the item being iterated as well as the selection from the radio inputs:

JS:

```
$scope.foo = function(x, selection) {
  switch(selection) {
    case 'Name':
      return x.Name;
      break;
    case 'City':
      return x.City;
      break;
    case 'Country':
      return x.Country;
    default:
      return x.Name;
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
<select ng-model="selectedName" ng-options="x.Name as foo(x, selection) for x in names"></select>
```

Here is a [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/CGoVfC6oESiOZujsg2bB?p=preview) showing `ng-options` with `as` syntax utilizing a function for conditional label dropdown display.

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: Thanks alot. This is what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

You could combine your `ng-repeat`'s and use a filter on the options.

html

```
            <select class="form-control" ng-model="selectedName">
                <option value="" selected disabled>Select Name</option>
                <option ng-repeat="n in names" value="{{n.Name}}">{{n.Name | filter:isSelection('Name')}}</option>
                <option ng-repeat="n in names" value="{{n.Country}}">{{n.Country| filter:isSelection('Country')}}</option>
                <option ng-repeat="n in names" value="{{n.City}}">{{n.City| filter:isSelection('City')}}</option>
            </select>
```

JS

```
$scope.isSelection = function(x){
    return x == $scope.selection;
}
```

Each `ng-repeat` uses the filter with a string of what type of selection it is. This will filter out any option that is not of the same `selection`